# Casting and interface inheritance

Tags: c#, inheritance, interface, casting

Each item has an interface, `IItem`. As well as this, there is a interface known as `IDrawableItem` which inherits from Item.

The code below, is trying to draw a drawable item, but cannot as the collection this class stores accepts only `IItem`. You can add anything that inherits from `IItem` to this class, but using other methods can only be achieved by casting.

```
foreach (var item in Items) {
    item.Draw();               // The casting would go here.
}
```

I know how to cast, `as` etc... but is this acceptable? Is it a best practice?

Just wondering if there are other ways to handle such scenarios.

Comment: The code below, is trying to draw a drawable item, but cannot as the collection this class stores accepts only IItem. - WHY? Tell us a bit about the design. Can you change it?

Comment: Jason's code will get you out of your dilemma.  The issue is whether this is the right design for your objects, and that's really hard to say from 2 lines of description.

Comment: Perhaps use a collection which stores IDrawbleItem s instead?

Comment: This is just a quick prototype, so is subject to change. I can't use a list of drawable items as there is another type of item which could potentially be added.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use [`Enumerable.OfType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913.aspx) to extract only those elements of `Items` that implement `IDrawableItem`:

```
foreach(var item in Items.OfType<IDrawableItem>()) {
    item.Draw();
}
```

To address the question that Nanook asked in the comments the above code will probably be translated into code equivalent to the following:

```
foreach(var item in Items) {
     if(item is IDrawableItem) {
        ((IDrawable)item).Draw();
     }
}
```

Of course, really there is an iterator behind the scenes that looks something like this:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> OfType<T>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source) {
    if(source == null) {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("source");
    }
    foreach(TSource item in source) {
        if(item is T) {
            yield return (T)item;
        }
    }
}
```

So, what this shows is that we probably only iterate through `Items` once. Of course, there is no requirement that `OfType` is implemented like the above but this is the sensible thing to do.

Comment: Does this example actually perform 2 loops? 1 to get the IDrawableItems and another to loop through them and call Draw. If so, this is not very performant.

Comment: Nop, it doesn't. All Linq.Enumerable methods are implemented by using a custom Enumerator. The code above would translate into something like foreach (var item in items) { if item is IDrawableItem yield return item as IDrawableItem; }

Comment: Excellent, just what I needed. So while it is the same as my original plan to cast behind the scenes - OfType<> is much nice way of doing it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Two alternative solutions:

- Keep the drawables in a separate collection.
- Add `DrawIfPossible()` method to `IItem`. `IDrawableItem` should override it to call `Draw()`, other `IItem()` implementors should have an empty implementation.

Explicit type querying is considered a sign that there might be something wrong with the design.

Comment: As I've said, this is a quick prototype which is likely to change. Though I do agree about your last point regarding the design.

Comment: Wasn't meant as critique. There are cases when type querying is necessary. Quick hacks, frameworks passing objects as `ICastItDownAsNeeded`, etc.